# How to defer jury duty in USA that may conflict with a scheduled trip?

Tags: usa, uk, air-travel, legal

My fiancee and I are in a long-distance relationship and have not seen each other since August 2019. She has flights booked to the UK from Dec. 26 2019 to Jan. 18 2020 flying in from USA.

She received a letter today saying she's been selected for jury duty between January 2020 and April 2020.

She has her flights already booked and we've some stuff planned for these three weeks. Is there any option to postpone jury service? We're worried she may not even be able to travel away for the 3 weeks now and that the flights plus the cost will be lost. Such bad luck. We actually don't even know the actual date and worried the jury service may take place in January while she is in the UK.

She lives in Ohio, USA.

Comment: As a US citizen in New Jersey, I've *never* gotten a jury selection summons that did not specify the date I was to report. I'm surprised Ohio would do that. Unless this was for a grand jury and not a petit jury?  (Grand juries decide whether to indict, petit juries decide the outcome of a case)

Comment: IIRC the time I was called in Pennsylvania I was given a concrete date for selection, but an extended range for duty beyond that point in the initial letter because they were selecting juries for a number of upcoming trials.

Comment: Not a travel question :)

Comment: If you can say which court has called your fiancée, I would like to have a look at its website to see whether there is any more specific information I could add to my answer.

Comment: As others have said, postponing jury duty because of travel plans is perfectly normal and acceptable. The courts don't want to impose undue burden on the jurors by forcing the cancellation of (possibly non-refundable) travel. But your fiancee should **request the postponement as soon as possible**, to give the court plenty of time to find a replacement. If they delay too long, the court will be less likely to grant the postponement.

Comment: Surely there's a number you can call or other instructions on the summons? Why don't you start with that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a travel question. It's a civic duty question.

Answer (score 28):

I don't know specifically about Ohio, but I've been called for both federal and state jury service in New York.  In both cases, I was called for a time during a trip out of town.  In both cases, I received a postponement because of my plans.  If I recall correctly, my statement to that effect was sufficient to have the service postponed without having to submit any actual evidence, though I remember having the impression that subsequent postponements might be scrutinized more closely.  I suppose the statement was a signed statement under penalty of perjury, but I do not remember precisely.

Postponement of jury service because of travel is surely routine in Ohio as well.  It should not be too hard to arrange.  If there is no information about this in the letter she received, it will surely be mentioned in the actual summons.  If the court that has called your fiancée does want evidence beyond her own statement, a photocopy of an airline reservation will almost certainly suffice.

(On the off chance that your fiancée is not a US citizen or is otherwise unqualified for jury service, of course, she should instead present evidence of her disqualification to the court instead of asking for a postponement.)